# Puppet CSR Issue using external certificates

Tags: puppet, csr

I am hoping that someone might be able to help me with a CSR (Certificate Singing Request) issue that I am facing. I currently have a Puppet server and Puppet agent on a single server. However, I am using external certificates for these. The Puppet server and Puppet agent should have there own individual certificates. I am hopping for some advice on how to stop the agent trying to send a CSR as we are not using puppet's internal Certificates.

The Issue that I am seeing is when I run `/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver ca list --all`
I see the following error:

```
Fatal error when running action 'list'
  Error: Failed connecting to https://server.altname.example.com:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key
  Root cause: SSL_read: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

I then went on to check the status of the agent and when I run `service puppet status` I can see the following error:

```
server puppet-agent[7056]: Failed to submit the CSR, HTTP response was 404
```

Note; the puppet server and agent are in a running state.

This is showing that there is a CSR issue. However, I don't think this should be happening as I am using external Certificates that I have set up on the machine.

I have also updated the `ca.cfg` file to disable the certificate authority as I had read this need to be done when using external certificates. This file looks like this:

```
#puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-service/certificate-authority-service
puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-disabled-service/certificate-authority-disabled-service
puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.watcher.filesystem-watch-service/filesystem-watch-service
```

I have also updated the `webserver.conf` file to point to where the certificates are located.

```
webserver: {
    access-log-config: /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/request-logging.xml
    client-auth: want
    ssl-host: 0.0.0.0
    ssl-port: 8140
    ssl-cert: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/server.altserver.example.com.puppetserver.pem
    ssl-key: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/server.altserver.example.com.puppetserver.pem
    ssl-ca-cert: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
}
```

The certificates are located at `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/`
When running a tree on the directory this looks like:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/
├── certificate_requests
├── certs
│   ├── ca.pem
│   ├── server.altserver.example.com.pem
│   └── server.altserver.example.com.puppetserver.pem
├── crl.pem
├── private
├── private_keys
│   ├── puppet.altserver.example.com.pem
│   ├── server.altserver.example.com.pem
│   └── server.altserver.example.com.puppetserver.pem
└── public_keys
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, If you need any more information please ask.

Thank you.

I am running this on a `Ubuntu 22.04` server, and the puppet version is `7.28.0`.

Comment: Puppet documents the [requirements and procedure for using an external CA](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/config_ssl_external_ca.html).  You appear to be looking for option 2, "Single CA".  Note well that if you disable the puppet server's CA, which indeed you do need to do for this configuration, then you cannot expect to use any of the `puppetserver ca` subcommands.

Answer (score 0):

If the agent is issuing a CSR, then that means it doesn't think it has a valid certificate yet.  As described in [the Puppet documentation](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/config_ssl_external_ca.html#config_puppet_agent), you shouldn't need to change the agent's configuration file, but you do need to store in the appropriate locations: the agent's cert, the corresponding private key, the cert for the CA that signed it (which must be the same for agent and server), and the CA's CRL (or at least *a* CRL for the CA).

I can't tell you whether the names and locations in which you've stored the necessary files are correct for your installation, but Puppet can:

- `puppet config print hostcert --section agent`
- `puppet config print hostprivkey --section agent`
- `puppet config print localcacert --section agent`
- `puppet config print hostcrl --section agent`

If you change `--section agent` to `--section server` in those commands then Puppet will tell you where the puppetserver's documents should reside.  For server and agent on the same host, the CA cert and CRL might be the same location for server and agent.

IMPORTANT NOTE: execute those commands as the appropriate user.  That's root for the agent commands, and the puppetserver user (maybe "puppet") for the server commands.

Do also make sure that the permissions on those files and the directories in the path to them allow the relevant processes to access them.  The agent ordinarily runs as root, so there is *probably* no issue on that side, but the server ordinarily runs as an unprivileged user.

Comment: Running the commands shows that the files are correct for the installation, and paths are correct. If we forget about the puppetserver CA commend as that wont work. Then I am still facing the issue with the CSR the agent is sending. I can't seem to work out why it is doing this. As the Certificate is valid but it does not think it is. And the relevant files are stored in the correct location(s).

Comment: @CallumMcCrorie, do note that whereas you can and should forget about the puppetserver CA, you *cannot* ignore setting up the server's cert / key / cacert / crl.  It might be that on the same machine, agent and server share some of these, but not necessarily.  And they have nothing directly to do with puppetserver's built-in CA functionality.

Comment: If indeed all the files are set up correctly, then I can only speculate about why the agent keeps trying to issue a CSR.  It might just be that once it generated a CSR, it insists on trying to get it signed, despite subsequent reconfiguration mooting that.  There might also be an issue with the user as whom the agent is running.  Different users have their own, independent Puppet metadata.  Effectively, the agent running as me is a logically distinct endpoint from the agent running as root on the same machine.

Comment: The agent and server are both running as root user. This should mean that they have the correct permissions they need for this to work.